# Level Grinding Before Wallace In ORAS

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I was wondering if anyone knew what place would be most efficient in grinding levels for pokemon levels 40+, before facing Wallace in Sootopolis City for the 8th Gym Badge.

Comment: I don't think you need to grind in Gen3 games, but since I haven't played ORAS yet, I can't say for sure, but usually, you can surf around the vast extent of sea and look for swimmers or other trainers on patches of sand. But otherwise, I never had to grind levels past the 2nd gym in the original version.

Comment: Well my team is somewhat as I feel a bit under-leveled after facing Kyogre...

Comment: @SentinelGaming - What about the Mauville foodcourt? (I only just got there, dunno how the levels scale)

Comment: I am surprised you are underlevelled. In my playthrough I reached sootopolis and kyogre with my team mostly around 45. My starter was 50 I think. I did not grind anything, anywhere. Do you have exp.share on?

Comment: @SentinelGaming ^this. I find I'm way overlevelled. I walked into Mauville, went straight to the Gym (Wattson), and rolled it, without healing from the Route before. My Pokemon were a level higher than Wattson's, and several higher than the regular trainers.

Comment: No it's just that I skip most trainer battles and what I meant by "under leveled" was around the 40's since the Elite 4 is coming up.As for Kyogre I accidentally KO'd it with Swampert. Well I managed to beat Wallace primarily with my Mega Glalie using Freeze-Dry.

Comment: Ok, I'm on my way to Mossdeep and my starter is 50 while my main team stands at 45-47... I'm way overlevelled lol (and I haven't been grinding at all).

Comment: Yeah i effortlessly steamrolled Wallace with my Sceptile and Manetric

Answer (score 1):

The food court will give you some good trainers.  However, if you have access to online, you can get usually get some pretty decent trainers and exp by fighting trainers in their Secret Bases after you "pass" them online.

Comment: The food courts levels are like lvl17, how is this a good way of leveling up?

Answer (score -1):

I would say go to victory road, as you can enter it before beating Wallace         (Who I thought was a girl with a weird name)  Also the pokemon there range from 40-45 and you can catch Larion if you don't already have one.

Comment: You can't enter Victory Road before the 8th Gym..